# Yearning without Hope

Tags: vocabulary, connotation

I was reading Poe and thinking about his work. Then I thought his dark-romantic style seems like a huge yearning without any hope but I was not sure if this is possible. Does the word yearning contain hope by definition? I searched for this on the internet and dictionaries but could not settle the problem.

Comment: In this expression, yearning is a strong desire (unfortunately hopeless in that case).

Comment: Which definition of *hope*?  One definition of *yearning* might be "hoping for something", where *hope* means essentially *desire*.  But a different definition of *hope* might be stated as "the belief in the possibility of something", where, eg, I might *hope* that I will win the lottery, even though I know the odds are dismal.  So in one sense "yearning without hope" is self-contradictory, while in the other sense (and the one that most readers would assume) it means yearning without possibility of fulfillment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can indeed haave a **yearning hope** for something, yearning itself is

> a feeling of intense longing for something.

So yearning for something doesn't intrinsically include hope, no.

Edit: would probably be better if I explained why this is the case. I could, say, yearn for a reconciliation with my ex-girlfriend, even though I know for a fact it will never happen. Therefore, I have yearning without hope.

Comment: +1. Some relevant evidence: the phrase "yearning for the past" is well-attested.

Answer (score -1):

I think yearning contains hope. I've been pondering what does yearning become in the absence of hope, maybe grief.

Comment: I think that **yearning without hope** and **grief** are two different emotions. That's not to say that yearning without hope can't lead to grief, it often does; particularly in those who have experienced the death of someone close.